# Module build failed: Error: ENOENT webpack/buildin/global.js

Tags: node.js, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, laravel-mix

I've tried removing package-lock.json, node_modules, and reinstalling with npm install. However, that has not fixed the issue. It's weird because the Webpack works just fine. However, after editing a Vue.js file a couple of times then it starts throwing the following error.

**Error**

> Uncaught Error: Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or
> directory, open
> '/home/company/laravel-vue-crud-starter/node_modules/webpack/buildin/global.js'
> at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/webpack/buildin/global.js:1)
> at Object../node_modules/webpack/buildin/global.js (app.js:6924)
> at webpack_require (app.js:20)
> at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.common.dev.js:12010)
> at Object../node_modules/vue/dist/vue.common.dev.js (app.js:6867)
> at webpack_require (app.js:20)
> at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.common.js:2)
> at Object../node_modules/vue/dist/vue.common.js (app.js:6878)
> at webpack_require (app.js:20)
> at eval (webpack-internal:///./resources/js/app.js:2)

**Steps To Reproduce**

When initially compiling with npm run watch, it works. However, after a couple of saves, it starts throwing ENOENT errors.

Laravel Mix Version: 6.0.27
Node Version: 14.17.5
NPM Version: 6.14.14
OS: CentOS

Comment: It's probably another module. Can you show your webpack config associated with laravel mix?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy [link]https://pastebin.com/tcKq2i2M[/link] two files apparently.

Comment: The app can't find the file /home/company/laravel-vue-crud-starter/node_modules/webpack/buildin/global.js.